# How to detect if a client has crashed (or exit) for a server using Qt

Tags: qt, sockets

The client use ssh login and start up a server on remote machine, then the clinet create a tcp connect to the server.
The server need exit when the client has exit normally or crashed or network is dropped.
So the question is how to detect if the client which the server has connected to is crashed.

The first try is using error() signal, catch QAbsoluteSocket::NetworkError to determine the network has dropped. But I can't receive error() signal at all even if i pull out the network cable.

The second try is using the SocketState, i think whenever SocketState is UnconnectedState,the client may has exit normally and the server should exit too. This way works fine for "normal exit", but I don't know how to deal with "crash" and "dead network".

Help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, the only way you will know there is a problem with a socket connection is when you try to read or write with it. There are some exceptions: Windows will change the state of sockets if the network cable is unplugged, Linux (in my experience) will not.

The most reliable way to detect connection problems is to have the client regularly send a small message at an agreed upon interval with the server. If the server does not see this message within a reasonable time, it should consider the client dead and drop the connection. This will also give both sides regular opportunities to detect a problem via reads and writes.

Comment: Thanks! I think your solution is just like SO_KEEPALIVE Judge Maygarden mentioned. the different is sending and detecting "keep-alive" message by yourself or by the system. I will try it, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using [TCP keep alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html). It is not exposed through the public [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtcpsocket.html) interface, but you can use [setsockopt](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) with [QAbstractSocker::socketDescriptor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractsocket.html#socketDescriptor) to activate the [SO_KEEPALIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) feature.

**EDIT:** It appears that keep alive was added to QAbstractSocket at some point. So, simply call [QAbstractSocket::setSocketOption](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption) with [QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractsocket.html#SocketOption-enum).

You can find information about adjusting the timeout of keep alive request here: http://www.gnugk.org/keepalive.html

Comment: Thanks very much! But the default SO_KEEPALIVE timeout is 2 hours, so it means that if the socket has been idle for 2 hours ,the server will detect if the network has dead.  two hours may be too long, because the client may has been terminate(or killed) many times. so there may be a lot of no-use process living in the remote machine. But you let me know mean of SO_KEEPALIVE, thanks very much!

Comment: @jnblue What is your target platform(s) (e.g. Windows, Linux, etc.)?

Comment: The client is aimed to be a cross platform soft, and the server is Linux.

Comment: @jnblue Then decrease the timeout on your server. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

Comment: @jnblue A better solution might be to change the keepalive time of the individual socket. You can do it with setsockopt() and TCP_KEEPIDLE. Just a word of warning, it isn't available on many operating systems.